# Compound IF statement scope

Tags: c

```
if()//first if
{
  if()//second if
   statement;
}
else
 statement;
```

I know that `else` matches with the first `if` but my question is why?I think of it like this,first `if` and `else` are in the same scope(mains local scope for example) and the second `if` is in the first if local scope in which `else` has no visibility?Is this correct?

Comment: Your explanation sounds about right - is that all you're asking?

Comment: `else` matches the last `if` statement, excluding the ones wrapped in brackets (in a more local scope). so yes, that is correct

Comment: @TaylorFlores i know that i have written lots of code as a university student but when i ask professors on questions like this they reply,"if there is an if statement in an if block then it is invisible to the else outside of the block".I was hoping to get a better explanation here.

Comment: I do not understqand the question

Comment: If you really want to understand how stuff like this is parsed you  have to understand context free grammars

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes but if someone could explain it a little more i would be thankfull...

Comment: @user1478167 FYI, stuff that's declared inside the first `if` (**but outside of the inner `if`!**) has its scope continued in the statement following the `else` keyword.

Comment: C99: "An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the syntax".  Associating the `else` in your example to the second `if` is not permitted by the syntax because of the braces around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic syntax of `if....else` is:

```
              --optional-
if(expr) stmt [else stmt]
```

and if you just had your example minus the braces they'd nest this way:

```
         ---------stmt----------
if(expr) if(expr) stmt else stmt
```

basically meaning that the `else` gets bound with the most recent available `if`,
and the syntax for the outer `if` is satisfied, since the inner `if...else` is a statement

Adding the braces gives (with the overall syntax shown again first):

```
if(expr)       stmt       [else stmt]

         --compound-stmt--
if(expr) { if(expr) stmt } else stmt
```

Here, then inner `if(expr)`..stmt is enclosed inside a compound statement (which is a subvariety of a statement), and the most recently still-open (read: in scope) `if` is the first one.   You could also view the end of a compound statement - the close brace - as closing off all contained syntactic structures.

There is no `compound if`, only an `if` controlling a compound statement.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax goes as follows:

```
'if' '(' <condition> ')' <statement-1> [ 'else' <statement-2> ]
```

There is one statement that follows `if`, and one statement that follows the optional `else`. Each statement could be a *block statement*, in which case you must enclose it in a pair of curly braces.

Since you do have curly braces, the nested `if` is a `<statement-1>` in the syntax above; therefore, `else` belongs to the outer `if`.

Note that if you remove the curly braces, `else` would belong to the inner `if`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason `else` matches the first `if` is because you're forcing it to with the `{` and `}`

what `{` and `}` do is they take any number of statements and turn it into a "block" of code, which is treated by control statements(like `if`)similar to a single statement

IF your code didn't put the second if statement into a block like the following

```
if()//first if
  if()//second if
   statement;
else
 statement;
```

then the `else` would actually correspond to the **second** `if`

Answer (score 3):

"I know that else matches the first if but my question is why?"

Why was it *designed* that way?

So that there could be statements like this:

```
if (istrue)
    if (thatstrue) dosomething ();
    else donothing2 ();
else donothing1 ();
```

Without otherwise having to write brackets, like this:

```
if (istrue){
    if (thatstrue) dosomething ();
    else donothing2 ();
} else donothing1 ();
```

Also note that the tabbing is irrelevant - it does not affect which `else` statement is executed.